# Short tale from Asimov's Science Fiction - children's psychic abilities tested after mankind is defeated by a race of teleporting aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, pulp

I'm trying to locate a short tale I read sometime ago in an old number of *Asimov's Science Fiction*. I've trying to find it here and checking old magazines to no avail. The plot went like this:

Mankind had been defeated in 50 minutes by a race of teleporting aliens, and forced to pay tribute by the way of testing children's psychic abilities. The kids were told to walk in a sort of corridor with a gate to the alien planet. If they had the shining or whatever they walked away never to be seen again.

After an incident in which a brain wired kid had returned and forced to be sent back, the military had put soldiers in the centers, reasoning that one thing was send the children away and another letting them recapture escapees. Anyway, the main guy has discovered the aliens hopped in a regular pattern, and thus the soldiers could be trained to shoot where the aliens would appear instead of where they were.

When a boy got stuck in the middle of the gate, leaving it open, they invaded the aliens planet, which was undefended, and then there were US flags and cake for everyone. The children were being used as wetware computer cores for FTL starships, by the way.

Comment: [Low Grade Ore](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42841/id-this-story-aliens-test-earthling-children-for-psychic-powers)

Comment: I knew I'd seen the question on this site before :-) It was indeed in Asimov's in 1977. Please let us know if this is your story so we can mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Indeed it is. Many thanks! Sorry for the duplicate!

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Don't worry about the duplicate - we've been running for 13 years and over such a long time it's inevitable stories get asked about more than once. Welcome to the site :-)

Comment: @Álvaro - closing as a duplicate is not intended as a criticism; no need to apologize.  While it is worthwhile to first search the site in case your question has already been answered, sometimes we miss; that is why we can mark things as duplicates.